# How to get AppBar height in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, appbar

How can I get the height of an **AppBar** in Flutter?
I am using the MarialApp Widget ('package:flutter/material.dart').
I have the height of my Context and would like to deduct the height of the appbar.

```
final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Comment: You can get the height of any `Widget` in Flutter and `AppBar` is a regular `Widget`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot OP asked HOW to get the height of the `AppBar` and you just said you can get height of the `AppBar`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is not an ideal way, I think, but it will work.

*Firstly* declare the `AppBar` widget that you will use in your `Scaffold`.

```
Widget demoPage() {
  AppBar appBar = AppBar(
    title: Text('Demo'),
  );
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: appBar,
    body: /*
    page body
    */,
  );
}
```

*Now* you can get the **height** of your `appBar` using its `preferredSized`:

```
double height = appBar.preferredSize.height;
```

You can use this height to reduce from the **screen height**.

```
final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Comment: I don't really get how to reduce appBar.preferredSize.height. Is that possible? thanks a lot. I tried to change the value of `kToolbarHeight`, but failed due to it's a const var.

Comment: I figured it out how to. By extending AppBar class `class MyAppBar extends AppBar` and then set `preferredSize` manually.

Comment: You can simply use `AppBar().preferredSize.height` If you find it to be neater. It will produce the same result as the above but will be creating another instance of AppBar

Comment: bonus knowledge:- deduct the height of status bar by using MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top

Comment: it worded nice. but can we know exactly how to get height from media query?

Comment: `appBar.preferredSize.height` = `kToolbarHeight ` = `56.0` but `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight` is exactly what I want to get.

Comment: Just remember that if you are inside a scaffold, it might override MediaQuery.padding - so you'll just get 0. Instead use : Scaffold.of(context).appBarMaxHeight; credits go to @na2axl !

Answer (score 69):

There is no need to store the `AppBar` instance, or to create a dummy one to get the height. Also, `AppBar.preferredSize` will always return the same value of `56.0`, which is the standard of Material Design, and this value will not be always usable for some cases (it lacks the height of the status bar for example).

Since an `AppBar` is surely used with a `Scaffold`, IMHO, the smarter way to get the real `AppBar` height (the distance between the top of the device and the top of the `Scaffold` body) is to use:

```dart
double height = Scaffold.of(context).appBarMaxHeight;
```

With this, the computed height will include (independently of the platform):

- The status bar height
- The app bar height
- The bottom app bar widget height if any (ex. TabBar)

Hope this will help!

Comment: How does that help you get the bottom bar height as well? I don't think my bottom bar and app bar are the same height.

Comment: Hi @Graham, by "bottom app bar widget", I mean the widget who is placed at the bottom of the AppBar (with the Appbar.bottom property), a TabBar for exemple. I don't mean the BottomAppBar widget who is placed at the bottom of the Scaffold.

Comment: For me this just returns 56 which is not the appbar+statusbar.

Comment: This is the only viable solution. Scaffold will override MediaQuery, and you will keep getting padding.top == 0 all the time.

Comment: May i ask how u reach scafold when ur building appBar as separate class/widget?

Answer (score 68):

you can use this :

```
var height = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
```

this way is very sample and easy

Comment: I like this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

There is a constant for the normal toolbar height: `kToolbarHeight`

Comment: it says 56, and it's too short

Comment: @AlirezaAkbari Because you need to also deduct MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top thanks to Avnish Kumar

Answer (score 37):

Just watch in AppBar

```
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight
```

Answer (score 24):

Get body height:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight)
```

I hope, this solution will also help you. Thanks to ask this question.

Comment: awesome, smart solution for get height of body. thankyou brother!

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top  -> it gives status bar height,
kToolbarHeight -> it gives toolbar height, Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

AppBar has a fixed height of 56.

You should create your own appbar implementing PreferredSizeWidget

```
class TestAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('TEST'),
      centerTitle: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(34);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get height of AppBar by using:

```
double height = appBar.preferredSize.height;
```

Make sure you have declared AppBar widget.

Answer (score 2):

`kToolbarHeight`  is default Appbar's height

`kBottomNavigationBarHeight` is default bottom navigation height

this will perfectly center align your progress indicator

```dart
    SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (kToolbarHeight + kBottomNavigationBarHeight),
            child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
```

Answer (score 1):

AppBer hight increase .
You use PreferredSize and set height

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
            child: AppBar(
              child : Text(" ");
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: There's a lot of code in this answer. Please [edit] to explain how it answers the question.

Comment: `Size.fromHeight` is offered in 3 other solutions.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Within the Widget build you need to get the height and width of a standard AppBar, then use the values to declare a Size object and then input the height and width as arguments.

You can do so as follows for a custom AppBar that I have called MyAppBar()

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//get the height and width of a standard appBar to use with custom Appbar

var appBarWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
var appBarHeight = AppBar().preferredSize.height;

return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size(appBarWidth, appBarHeight),
    child: MyAppBar(),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  @override
  final Size preferredSize; // default is 56.0

  WidgetAppBar({@required this.appBarTitle, @required this.appBarColor, Key key}) : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(40), super(key: key);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26217297)

Answer (score 0):

This will give height of appbar or statusbar

```js
var height = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
```

However, this will work only in mobile devices, other devices don't have status bar

Answer (score 0):

Use preferred size of appBar to get height of AppBar.

```
var appBarHeight = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of AppBar height is 56.0 but

You can get with code

```
double height = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use preferred size

```
//defined as
Size preferredSize
```

**preferred size** is a size whose height is the sum of kToolbarHeight and the bottom widget's preferred height.

Scaffold uses this size to set its app bar's height.

It is defined like below in app bar class which implement PreferredSizeWidget

```
 preferredSize = new Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + (bottom?.preferredSize?.height ?? 0.0))
```

a link for example ...

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart