# How to get the height for the system navigation bar?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to get the height of the system navigation bar so that I can calculate the height of other widgets accordingly.

I was able to get the height of the screen. Is there a way to get the usable height?

> usable_height = total_height-(status_bar_height +
>   navigation_bat_height)

I'm using this method to get the total screen size:

```
double getScreenHeight(BuildContext context) {
  return MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Widget`s need to know the size available to them then you can wrap them in `LayoutBuilder` which will have the width and height available to you `Widget`

Watch official sample here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYDVcriKjsw

Some examples:

- [How can I layout widgets based on the size of the parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558368/how-can-i-layout-widgets-based-on-the-size-of-the-parent)
- https://flutterwidgets.io/widget-of-the-week-layoutbuilder.html

---

But if want to know the `AppBar` height then [AppBar height in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075945/appbar-height-in-flutter)