# Flutter: How to make a ListView's height match_parent in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, layout

ListView's height should be as windows's height. So when keyboard opens, user can scroll down to see the widgets which covered by keyboard. And Widgets shouldn't change their position. I've used Align widget to position them, and wrapped with a Stack widget. In other words: it should be exactly as Instagram login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps: 
demo : https://i.ibb.co/g7C3K7K/dmeo.gif

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Welcome to the login page",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Name"),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content:
                          Text("I won't say your name but stay home, stay safe!"),
                    ));
                  },
                  child: Text("Say my name"))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to align the button to bottom of the screen. So this margin with SizedBox approach isn't gonna be responsive in screens with different height

Comment: @AbdulazizAbduqodirov check the latest edited answer

Comment: Thank you. It worked. One more question: can we do that with AppBar?

Comment: If you want an sticky appbar which will not scroll then add an appbar in your scaffold.
If you want an appbar that will scroll then add app bar in the column. Cheers

Comment: I've used the sticky appbar. But it affected to height. After adding appbar the Container which is wrapped with SingleChildScrollView is drawn higher than screen. So buttons aligned to bottom is not visible

Comment: If you want to use stick then you will have to minus 56 from height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, set it to height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 56,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075945/appbar-height-in-flutter

Comment: You can use this to calculate the height and subtract it from the total height of the view