# Flutter ListView.Builder inside SingleChildScrollView not scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've just began Flutter. I made a HeaderComponent which shows the title "Home" at the top and I used the BubbleBottomNavbar plugin which is displayed at the bottom.
For the moment, I'm using a list of strings as a mock but will later get a lists of news from an API an loop to display as cards.

I tried to create as many components as I can and wrap them to reuse the same "MainContainer" everywhere. This one will show the HeaderComponent and a list of widgets it will receive in parameters as content.

I want to it to be a scrollable view by default. All its widgets in content are well displayed but I keep seeing the "bottom overflowed ..." warning. I tried many components and different way to fix this using Flex component, Expandable, ... but I still can't scroll and keep this warning

This is my App Render :

[image: iPhone App Preview]

Here are my build methods :

MainComponent.dart :
[image: MainComponent]

PostsComponent.dart :
[image: PostsComponent]

Thank you for the help you'll provide me

Comment: from where you are calling getPostCells?

Comment: Height of the container shouldn't be MediaQuery.of(context).size.height. That would include the height of the appbar and the bottom navigation bar. U can remove the extra space directly (by using 0.8x of the height or something) or like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075945/how-to-get-appbar-height-in-flutter)

Comment: @jitsm555 from the PostsComponent.dart build method

Comment: add mediaQuery.size.height -
                      appBar.preferredSize.height -
                      mediaQuery.padding.top

Comment: I just removed both width and height property to the parent container in MainContainer.dart, I noticed they weren't even useful and weren't changing anything

Comment: stacking 2 scrollable widgets into each other is a bad idea (when they both use the same axis, in this case vertical). Just use a `Listview` in a `Column` or use a `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` or you use Slivers, like `SliverList`.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: I don't see why you have a container, a column, a singlechildscrollview and a listview! ListView itself is scrollable by default so you could have just used that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to have a **fixed header** and a **scrollable list** of posts beneath it. To achieve this, you want to structure the `build` method of your page like this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Column(children: <Widget>[
      HeaderComponent(title:"Home", hasBackButton:false),
      ListView.builder(
        ...
      ),
    ],
  )
}
```

Stacking 2 widgets, that are scrollable on the same axis, into each other, often results in bugs ("unlimited dimension", "overflow", etc.), because there is no clear scroll behaviour for where these 2 components overlap.

To implement a Sliver behaviour, use, well, Slivers, like [`SliverList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you have created a custom header and are not using an [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)? You can create a custom [PreferredSizedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSizeWidget-class.html) that you could pass to your scaffold if you need an excessively customized design (but you can do all elements of your design in the prebuilt `AppBar`).

It is recommended in the Flutter documentations for [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) to only use it if necessary, and instead use a ListView instead.

> When you have a list of children and do not require cross-axis shrink-wrapping behavior, for example a scrolling list that is always the width of the screen, consider ListView, which is vastly more efficient that a SingleChildScrollView containing a ListBody or Column with many children.

If you made your header an `AppBar`, you could then use `ListView.builder(...)` as the body of the scaffold.

But if you are insistent on using `SingleChildScrollView` for this use case, use a [ListBody](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListBody-class.html) with your externally built widgets passed in as children. If you want to do in-line generation of the list elements, you can use `List.generate` to generate the list in-line within `ListBody`.

Keep the `Column` on the outside, with the first child element of the `Column` your header, then the `SingleChildScrollView` with `ListBody` as its child with your list elements as the children.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
 children: <Widget>[
   Header(),
   SingleChildScrollView(
     child: ListBody(
       children: List.generate(...),
     ),
   )
 ],
);
```

EDIT: Or as the other user recommended, you could nest a `ListView` within the `Column` and eliminate the `SingleChildScrollView` entirely, which is more ideal and much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Hye, As I have struggled with finding the answer. But finally I solved it.

1. For those who wants their DataTable to scroll vertical as well as horizontal.

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(children: [
      Column(
        children: [
           SingleChildScrollView(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                 child: DataTable(
                          columns: [
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Storage Location')),
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Piece No ')),
                            ],
                          rows:
                              DataRow(
                                 cells: <DataCell>[
                                            DataCell(Text(element["LGORT"])),
                                            DataCell(Text(element["PCNO"])),
                                                  ],
                                     ),
                               ),
                            ),
                     ],
            ),
       ]),
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make the ListView.builder inside a container, so the builder know where to take its Size(Height,Width from).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Container(
     // You can add its height height here or you can leave it empty
     height : YourHeightValue,
     child: ListView.builder(
       ...
     ),
  )
}
```