# How to detect toolbar area height on devices?

Tags: flutter, height, padding, toolbar

In my application the screen is divided 2 sections. Bottom section has controls and top section has an image.
Top section is 75% of the total screen size.

And I want to place image in the middle of that section.

[image]

I got the height of the screen with

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

then bottom and top area curved area with

```
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom
```

But on iPhoneX padding top and bottom always return 0

The screen height seems to include these 2 areas.
How do I detect these area sizes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075945/how-to-get-appbar-height-in-flutter check this link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get AppBar height in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075945/how-to-get-appbar-height-in-flutter)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My problem is getting padding top/bottom values as 0.

Comment: I also don't have an Appbar, so it's height is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need to know the toolbar height.

You can simply wrap the body of your Scaffold widget in SafeArea widget. Then you give 75% to the top container. Then you add your image as a decoration with whatever `fit` property that you need. If images can be smaller, instead of adding image as a decoration, you can add it as Image widget wrapped in Center widget.

Comment: The problem is the image needs to be scaled. Also it can be paned. So I need to make sure it remain within the bounding area.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: I need to know the exact height of the area, so I can stop scaling the image when the edge reach the bounding area. Basically I need to know the height of safe area.

Comment: You can tell a Widget in Flutter to "take as much space as is available to you". There is no need to know the dimensions in pixels. You see a problem that does not exist.

Comment: I am scaling the image with Transform.scale. If I do not control the scale it will go beyond available area. It will NOT throw overflow error. Is there a way to restrict the scale to available area?

Comment: In the starting state the image does fit the container properly. After that I am scaling and translating the container.